# User Input and If-then and else

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to create a simple `20 questions game`, by taking user input to take user input and I'm fairly new to programming java.

I have set up all the strings for my questions and I want to ask the user if they want to play. I was trying to set up a `if-then` statement with the user input, with the number `1` being `Yes` and number `2` being `No`.

How could I set this up? I tried with my `if(in.nextInt() = a)` statement but I know that's not right. I know I need to reference the previous user input, but how do I do that? Thanks for all your help in advance.

```
import java.util.*;

public class twentyq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;

        // all the Strings needed for Questions[represented by the Q(1-20) variable] and their Answers[represented by the AQ(1-20) variable] 
        String Q1;
        String Q2;
        String Q3;
        String Q4;
        String Q5;
        String Q6;
        String Q7;
        String Q8;
        String Q9;
        String Q10;
        String Q11;
        String Q12;
        String Q13;
        String Q14;
        String Q15;
        String Q16;
        String Q17;
        String Q18;
        String Q19;
        String Q20;

        String AQ1;
        String AQ2;
        String AQ3;
        String AQ4;
        String AQ5;
        String AQ6;
        String AQ7;
        String AQ8;
        String AQ9;
        String AQ10;
        String AQ11;
        String AQ12;
        String AQ13;
        String AQ14;
        String AQ15;
        String AQ16;
        String AQ17;
        String AQ18;
        String AQ19;
        String AQ20;


        // The questions and their answers in numerical order question first then answer immediately following.
        Q1 = "Where would you find the Sea of Tranquility?";
        AQ1 = "The Moon.";

        Q2 = "What is the Capital of Spain";
        AQ2 = "Madrid.";

        Q3 = "What is the painting, La Gioconda, more usually known as?";
        AQ3 = "The Mona Lisa.";

        Q4 = "Which chess piece can only move diagonally?";
        AQ4 = "A Bishop.";

        Q5 = "What is the oldest surviving printed book in the world?";
        AQ5 = "The Diamond Sutra, dated at 868 AD.";

        Q6 = "Costing around $2,600 per pound, and made only to order by Knipschildt, what is the name of this chocolate truffle?";
        AQ6 = "Chocopologie";

        Q7 = "Who invented TV?";
        AQ7 = "George Carey, a Boston civil servant, first thought up television in 1876. John Logie Baird is often quoted as its inventor but his ideas didn't come along until the 1920's.";

        Q8 = "What is allspice alternatively known as?";
        AQ8 = "Pimento.";

        Q9 = "In publishing, what does POD mean?";
        AQ9 = "Print on demand.";

        Q10 = "What is John Leach famous for making?";
        AQ10 = "Pottery.";

        Q11 = "When was the euro introduced as legal currency on the world market?";
        AQ11 = "1st January, 1999.";

        Q12 = "How many valves does a trumpet have?";
        AQ12 = "3.";

        Q13 = "Which kind of bulbs were once exchanged as a form of currency?";
        AQ13 = "Tulips.";

        Q14 = "Name the director of the Lord of the Rings trilogy.";    
        AQ14 = "Peter Jackson.";

        Q15 = "Name the largest fresh water lake in the world?";
        AQ15 = "Lake Superior.";

        Q16 = "Name the seventh planet from the sun.";
        AQ16 = "Uranus.";

        Q17 = "Which country is Prague in?";
        AQ17 = "Czech Republic.";

        Q18 = "What is the oldest film ever made, and when was it made?";
        AQ18 = "Roundhay Garden Scene, made in 1888.";

        Q19 = "Name the three primary colors.";
        AQ19 = "Red, yellow and blue.";

        Q20 = "How old is the world's oldest dictionary?";
        AQ20 = "Cuniform tablets with bilingual Sumerian-Akkadian word-lists have been dated to 2300 BC.";

        System.out.println("Welcome To KCH39's 20 Questions!");
        System.out.println("Would you like to play? If yes, press 1 and enter. If not, press 2 and enter.");

        in.nextInt();

        if (in.nextInt() = a){
            system.out.println(Q1);


        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit:). Didn't realize I had messed that up.

Comment: You might want to read up on [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Simpler might be to have a class "Question". Then have 2 strings in this, "q" and "a" which hold the question and answer. Then add these to an array Question[20]. This would cut down the repetition a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the assignment operator instead of the equals operator:

```
if (in.nextInt() == a){
    system.out.println(Q1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, change  `(in.nextInt() = a)` to `(in.nextInt() == a)`

```
 if(in.nextInt() == a){
     System.out.println(q1);
    }
```

`=` is an assignment operator and `==` (equality operator) is used for comparsion.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: Now when I press 1 and hit enter it doesn't print the next line. How could I fix that?

Comment: change system.out.println() to System.out.println()?

Answer (score 0):

Use equals operator (==) rather then assignment(=)....

```
in.nextInt();

        if (in.nextInt() == a){
            system.out.println(Q1);


        }
```

other option is to assign that value first to another int and then check

```
int b == in.nextInt()

if(b==a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program throws following compiler error. Insteed of comparing you are trying to assign value of 'a' into in.nextInt() which is impossible.

```
twentyq.java:120: error: unexpected type
    if (in.nextInt() = a){
                  ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error
```

So it must be fixed as follows(i.e use double equals):

```
    if (in.nextInt() == a){
        System.out.println(Q1);
    }
```